# Excel VBA Clear Contents

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in excel sheet that contains the IF condition i.e.

```
=If(Cond 1 is TRUE, X, Y)
```

Now, after using this condition, i get certain values in the column. Following format can be considered (these are actual values):

```
4L  
4L  
4L  


4L
```

**Note:** The two empty cells in the above col  are an outcome of the TRUE condition(entry 4 and 5, i entered total 6 entries, two are empty cells ). Therefore, they are valid. (let me call the above col "A" for future reference)

Now, these empty cells actually contains formulas (the if condition). I want to **CLEARCONTENT** them using VBA but it is not working.

And I'm trying the below code:

```
If ActiveSheet.Cells(row_no, col_no) = "" Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(row_no, col_no).ClearContents
End If
```

But this does not work. I just want to CLEAR CONTENT those empty cells by running a loop over the whole column. The cells of the column where TEXT exist (i.e. 4L), that should be skipped but as soon the code encounters the EMPTY CELL (which actually have an IF condition), it should CLEAR CONTENT it and complete the loop. So the final result would be again the same as column "A", the only difference would be that the empty cells will be BLANK now i.e. they will not have any IF condition.

I do not have problem running the loops but i am not getting how to tell VBA about that empty cell and clear contenting it. Hopefully i was able to post a clear query. Thanking in advance.

Regards
Nayyar

Comment: Could you please share your code, it would help us to understand even better.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below sample code it should work..

```
Sub test()
'Assuming your data in column  A from A2

Set Rng = Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In Rng
    If cell.Value = "" Then
    cell.ClearContents
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

And in your formula `=If(Cond 1 is TRUE, X, Y)` your not giving any output like **""** which will give you blank. Please update it and then try :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well

```
If (Range("A35").Value = "") Then
    Range("A35").Formula = ""
End If
```